# Rails nested_attributes with three way has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

I have 3 tables (`products`, `custom_attribute`, `attribute_value`) that need to be linked together. I have `attribute_value_maps` table that has `product_id`, `custom_attribute_id`, and `attribute_value_id`.

My product model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :attribute_value_maps` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :attribute_values`.

My product form has a field for new attribute_values that looks like this:

```
<input id="product_attribute_values_attributes_1_custom_attribute_id" name="product[attribute_values_attributes][1][custom_attribute_id]" value="1" type="hidden">
<input id="product_attribute_values_attributes_1_attribute_value_name" name="product[attribute_values_attributes][1][name]">
```

The controller is basic `@product.update_attributes(paras[:product])`.

This creates the `attribute_value` record properly, but the `attribute_value_map` record saves with a nil `custom_attribute_id`.

**Question 1:** Is there a simple way to get the `attribute_value_map` record to save with the proper `custom_attribute_id` in this manner?

**Question 2:** Say there already was a map record, if I add an input with name `product[attribute_values_attributes][1][attribute_value_map_id]`, it just yells at me saying that's not a valid field.  How do I update an existing map record while creating a new attribute_value?

***Edit 1:  More detail requested***

product model:

```
has_many :custom_attributes, :through => :attribute_value_maps
has_many :attribute_value_maps, :dependent => :destroy
has_man :attribute_values, :through => :attribute_value_maps
accepts_nested_attributes_for :attribute_value_maps
accepts_nested_attributes_for :attribute_values
```

custom_attribute model

```
has_many :attribute_value_maps
```

attribute_value model

```
belongs_to :custom_attribute
has_many :attribute_value_maps
```

attribute_value_map model

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :custom_attribute
belongs_to :attribute_value
```

Comment: Can you post the relationship code you have between these 3 models? products, custom_attribute, attribute_value

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do here, I think you might be setting yourself up for a lot of pain using ActiveRecord.

This kind of dynamic attributes is why NoSQL databases were created.  You may want to consider whether something like Mongoid/MongoDB is a better option:

At the very least, you might want to consider looking at ActiveRecord's Serialize functionality:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html see the serialize function towards the bottom.

If you're using Postgres, you might want to look into the hstore extensions which uses a native database format to allow indexing of property fields:

https://github.com/softa/activerecord-postgres-hstore

Hopefully something above is helpful for you :)